# Acortar los títulos de los posts pero sólo en la preview

Tags: php, wordpress

estoy intentando truncar los títulos de los posts de mi blog en wordpress y lo he conseguido, pero me gustaría que sólo afectase a la previsualización y no al post. O sea, el título de la página del post quiero que esté entero.
El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
function max_title_length( $title ) {
    $max = 70;
    if( strlen( $title ) > $max ) {
    return substr( $title, 0, $max ). " &hellip;";
    } else {
    return $title;
    }
    }
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length');
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada debes entender donde esta lo que quieres hacer ... por ejemplo los titulos se manejan en: *functions.php*

hay entonces puedes agregar esto:

```
function max_title_length( $title ) {
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        // No truncar el título en la página del post
        return $title;
    } else {
        $max = 70;
        if ( strlen( $title ) > $max ) {
            return substr( $title, 0, $max ) . " &hellip;";
        } else {
            return $title;
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length' );
```

como podras observar estoy implementando: **is_singular()** esto esta en la documentacion de wordpress: [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/)

---

***Recurso en ingles:***

> Developer Resources Search reference
>
> *Browse: Home / Reference / Functions / is_singular()*
>
> is_singular( string|string[] $post_types = '' ): bool \ Determines
> whether the query is for an existing single post of any post type
> (post, attachment, page, custom post types).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @ArcanisGK507, realmente tu solución funciona perfectamente. Soy consciente que tengo que estudiarme un poco más a fondo la parte de Backend de Wordpress, es una de mis asignaturas pendientes. De todos modos, insisto en el agradecimiento, funciona como quería.
Un saludo.